# WPF: Should I manually call Close on windows opened by ShowDialog method?

Tags: wpf, window, dispose, showdialog

The thing is that WPF Window doesn't implement IDisposable interface which led me to believe, that I don't have to manually dispose of it when I open it by calling ShowDialog() but the first comment [on this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) states differently. Does anybody know what's the truth?

Answer (score 6):

Only if you open the window using Show() instead of ShowDialog().

From the documentation:

> If a window, opened by calling ShowDialog, and with a Button  with its IsCancel  property set to true, will automatically close when the button is either clicked, or ESC is pressed. If the window was opened using Show, however, Close must be explicitly called, such as from Click  event handler for the Button.

and:

> Closing a window causes the Closing  event to be raised. If the Closing  event isn't canceled, the following occurs:
>
> - The Window is removed from Application.Windows (if an Application object exists).
> - The Window is removed from the owner Window if the owner/owned relationship was established before the owned Window was shown and after the owner Window was opened.
> - The Closed event is raised.
> - Unmanaged resources created by the Window are disposed.
> - If ShowDialog was called to show the Window, ShowDialog returns.

Answer (score 0):

> How about the code below? implementing IDisposable on your form and removing all event handlers.
>   However, Is Microsoft already doing that on Close()?
>
> Also does manual GC.Collect help?

Some references and related posts:

[What is the correct way to dispose of a WPF window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568408/what-is-the-correct-way-to-dispose-of-a-wpf-window/569033#569033)

[What is the correct way to dispose of a WPF window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568408/what-is-the-correct-way-to-dispose-of-a-wpf-window)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MyForm.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyForm: IDisposable
    {        

      public MyForm()
      {}


      private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
      {            
        Dispose();
      }

      public void Dispose()
      {

        try{
             _resourcescollection.Clear();
             _resourcescoll = null;
             //close other resources
            }
        catch(exception ex)
        {}
        EventHelper.RemoveAllEventHandlers(_resources);
        EventHelper.RemoveAllEventHandlers(_timer);
        EventHelper.RemoveAllEventHandlers(_etc);
        EventHelper.RemoveAllEventHandlers(this);        
      }

      ~MyForm()
      {
        Dispose();
      }

    }
```

Comment: It would have been great if you could post your code properly.