# Memory Exception; NullReference; CA1001 implement IDisposable

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, nullreferenceexception, idisposable

I have small program that takes the links from a text file, pass those links to backend system at ImportIO, and save the results to a CSV. However I am seeing following errors after 15,20 min of run. I encounter two exception whichever comes first 
1. System.OutOfMemoryException
OR
2. System.NUllReferenceException
Both of these are however I feel my fault somewhere in the code. I am not an expert but I tried to use timer, or closing the files, or even setting objects to null. None worked or even using ArgumentNullException.
I ran the code analysis and it suggested that I should Idispose by this error.

> CA1001    Types that own disposable fields should be disposable   Implement
>   IDisposable on 'ImportIO' because it creates members of the following
>   IDisposable types: 'BlockingCollection>'.    Ostock  Main.cs 232

My code is as followed, I am not including importIO class it is long. I think solution is easy but I am just not on right path. Could you guys please help?

```
namespace MinimalCometLibrary
{
    class Program
    {
        private static CountdownEvent countdownLatch;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\James\Desktop\Exper\Input_Links\Stock_links.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {                
                string[] line = lines[i].Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                for (int j = 0; j < line.Length; j++)
                {

                 ImportIO io = new ImportIO("https://query.import.io", Guid.Parse("sdasd-asdasd-NoReal-3easdecb"), "NoReal=");
                /* Time Starts
                    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); // sw cotructor
                    sw.Start(); // starts the stopwatch
                    for (int b = 0; ; b++)
                    {
                        if (b % 1000 == 0) // if in 100000th iteration (could be any other large number
                        // depending on how often you want the time to be checked) 
                        {
                            sw.Stop(); // stop the time measurement
                            if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 25) // check if desired period of time has elapsed
                            {
                                break; // if more than 5000 milliseconds have passed, stop looping and return
                                // to the existing code
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sw.Start(); // if less than 5000 milliseconds have elapsed, continue looping
                                // and resume time measurement
                            }
                        }
                    }
                //Time Ends 
                 */   
                    io.Connect();
                    countdownLatch = new CountdownEvent(1);
                    // Query for tile SamsClub_Extractor, line[j]
                    Dictionary<String, Object> query1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    query1.Add("input", new Dictionary<String, String>() { { "webpage/url", line[j] } });
                    query1.Add("connectorGuids", new List<String>() { "189f34f3-0f82-4abb-8fbc-f353f35a255a" });
                    io.DoQuery(query1, HandleQuery);
                    countdownLatch.Wait(); 
                    io.Disconnect();

                }        

            }

            Environment.Exit(0);


        }


       private static void HandleQuery(Query query, Dictionary<String, Object> message)
        {

            if (message["type"].Equals("MESSAGE"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Got data!");
                string JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message["data"]);
                //Deserialize to strongly typed class i.e., RootObject
                RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JSON);

        // handle null reference
                if (obj == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("PleaseKeepRunning"); }


                //loop through the list and write to CSV file
                foreach (Result resultsItem in obj.results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(resultsItem.itemnbr + "-" + resultsItem.price +
                           "-" + resultsItem.product_name + "_" + obj.pageUrl);                   
                    string filePath = @"C:\Users\James\Desktop\Exper\Output_Files\StockPrice_NOW.txt";

                    //checking if file already exists, if not, create it:
                    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                    {
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew);
                        fs.Close();
                    }

                    //writing to a file (appending text):
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                            tw.WriteLine(resultsItem.itemnbr + "\t" + resultsItem.price + "\t" + resultsItem.product_name + "\t" + resultsItem.misc + 
                           "\t" +  resultsItem.qty + "\t" + obj.pageUrl);
                        fs.Close();
                    }

                    //Set object to null
                    obj = null;
                    obj.results = null;
                }

            }

            if (query.isFinished) countdownLatch.Signal();

        }        

   }    

//root Object

    public class Result
{

    public double price { get; set; }    
    public string itemnbr { get; set; }
    public string product_name { get; set; }
    public string qty { get; set; }
    public string misc { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<string> cookies { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public string pageUrl { get; set; }
    public string connectorGuid { get; set; }
    public string connectorVersionGuid { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
}
```

Please excuse my limited knowledge in .net. I am totally new to it. :)
Thanks

---- Edit
I used dispose and using as suggested but I am still facing the error. I am seeing error exception and debugger highlight this code of line in importIO.

> new Thread(new ThreadStart(PollQueue)).Start();

I also observe that stock.vshost.exe *32 also keep increasing memory and throw out of memory exception at any time after 70MB or something. I am including the importIO class code

```
class ImportIO 
    {
        private String host { get; set; }
        private int port { get; set; }


        private Guid userGuid;
        private String apiKey;


        private static String messagingChannel = "/messaging";
        private String url;


        private int msgId = 0;
        private String clientId;


        private Boolean isConnected;


        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();


        Dictionary<Guid, Query> queries = new Dictionary<Guid, Query>();


        private BlockingCollection<Dictionary<String, Object>> messageQueue = new BlockingCollection<Dictionary<string, object>>();


        public ImportIO(String host = "http://query.import.io", Guid userGuid = default(Guid), String apiKey = null)
        {
            this.userGuid = userGuid;
            this.apiKey = apiKey;


            this.url = host + "/query/comet/";
            clientId = null;
        }


        public void Login(String username, String password, String host = "http://api.import.io")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Logging in");
            String loginParams = "username=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username) + "&password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password);
            String searchUrl = host + "/auth/login";
            HttpWebRequest loginRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(searchUrl);


            loginRequest.Method = "POST";
            loginRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            loginRequest.ContentLength = loginParams.Length;


            loginRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;


            using (Stream dataStream = loginRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(loginParams), 0, loginParams.Length);


                HttpWebResponse loginResponse = (HttpWebResponse)loginRequest.GetResponse();




                if (loginResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Could not log in, code:" + loginResponse.StatusCode);
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (Cookie cookie in loginResponse.Cookies)
                    {
                        if (cookie.Name.Equals("AUTH"))
                        {
                            // Login was successful
                            Console.WriteLine("Login Successful");
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
        }


        public List<Dictionary<String, Object>> Request(String channel, Dictionary<String, Object> data = null, String path = "", Boolean doThrow = true)
        {
            Dictionary<String, Object> dataPacket = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
            dataPacket.Add("channel", channel);
            dataPacket.Add("connectionType", "long-polling");
            dataPacket.Add("id", (msgId++).ToString());


            if (this.clientId != null)
                dataPacket.Add("clientId", this.clientId);


            if (data != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Object> entry in data)
                {
                    dataPacket.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
                }
            }


            String url = this.url + path;


            if (apiKey != null)
            {
                url += "?_user=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userGuid.ToString()) + "&_apikey=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(apiKey);
            }


            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip");
            String dataJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<Object>() { dataPacket });


            request.ContentLength = dataJson.Length;


            request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;


            using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataJson), 0, dataJson.Length);
                try
                {
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


                    using (StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        String responseJson = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
                        List<Dictionary<String, Object>> responseList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<String, Object>>>(responseJson);
                        foreach (Dictionary<String, Object> responseDict in responseList)
                        {
                            if (responseDict.ContainsKey("successful") && (bool)responseDict["successful"] != true)
                            {
                                if (doThrow)
                                    throw new Exception("Unsucessful request");
                            }


                            if (!responseDict["channel"].Equals(messagingChannel)) continue;


                            if (responseDict.ContainsKey("data"))
                            {
                                messageQueue.Add(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)responseDict["data"]).ToObject<Dictionary<String, Object>>());
                            }


                        }


                        return responseList;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error occurred {0}", e.Message);
                    return new List<Dictionary<String, Object>>();
                }

            }


        }


        public void Handshake()
        {
            Dictionary<String, Object> handshakeData = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
            handshakeData.Add("version", "1.0");
            handshakeData.Add("minimumVersion", "0.9");
            handshakeData.Add("supportedConnectionTypes", new List<String> { "long-polling" });
            handshakeData.Add("advice", new Dictionary<String, int>() { { "timeout", 60000 }, { "interval", 0 } });
            List<Dictionary<String, Object>> responseList = Request("/meta/handshake", handshakeData, "handshake");
            clientId = (String)responseList[0]["clientId"];
        }


        public void Connect()
        {
            if (isConnected)
            {
                return;
            }

            Handshake();


            Dictionary<String, Object> subscribeData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            subscribeData.Add("subscription", messagingChannel);
            Request("/meta/subscribe", subscribeData);


            isConnected = true;


            new Thread(new ThreadStart(Poll)).Start();


            new Thread(new ThreadStart(PollQueue)).Start();
        }


        public void Disconnect()
        {
            Request("/meta/disconnect", null, "", true);
            isConnected = false;
        }


        private void Poll()
        {
            while (isConnected)
            {
                Request("/meta/connect", null, "connect", false);
            }
        }


        private void PollQueue()
        {
            while (isConnected)
            {
                ProcessMessage(messageQueue.Take());
            }
        }


        private void ProcessMessage(Dictionary<String, Object> data)
        {
            Guid requestId = Guid.Parse((String)data["requestId"]);
            Query query = queries[requestId];


            query.OnMessage(data);
            if (query.isFinished)
            {
                queries.Remove(requestId);
            }
        }


        public void DoQuery(Dictionary<String, Object> query, QueryHandler queryHandler)
        {
            Guid requestId = Guid.NewGuid();
            queries.Add(requestId, new Query(query, queryHandler));
            query.Add("requestId", requestId);
            Request("/service/query", new Dictionary<String, Object>() { { "data", query } });
        }




    }
```

Comment: When an exception is thrown the exception contains a stack trace. If you run your application in the debugger execution will break when the exception is thrown if it is unhandled and you should be able to see discover the source of your exceptions. `OutOfMemoryException` is simply that you are using more memory than is available. To fix the code analysis warning you need to modify the `ImportIO` class but the exceptions are not related to this somewhat minor issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say if your exceptions are related to it or not without seeing complete code, but the warning is about an issue "in" ImportIO, not in the code that's calling it (it's complaining that the ImportIO class does not implement IDisposable, not that you do something wrong with it)

Since you edited with the class : just implement IDisposable on your ImportIO class, here's a link on how to properly implement IDisposable : [Implementing IDisposable correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336856/implementing-idisposable-correctly)

Make sure to dispose of the BlockingCollection in the dispose of your ImportIO.

Then wrap your ImportIO in a using and the warning should go away. I'd be surprised if that alone caused those exceptions however but this is the way to fix your warning.

Comment: I have added class in my edit. May you please suggest something? Thanks

Comment: Added more info based on that, but i'm not sure your gut feeling that the exceptions are related to the warning is right. There's no reason that would cause a nullreference exception and you'd have to work with quite a bit of data for it to cause an outofmemory too.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling Dispose() method because as seen in your error message , it's a memory error because you keep opening files and reading them and then keeping the data there loaded on memory which causes the crash you see after some time

Try this :

```
     if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew);
                    fs.Close(); 
                    fs.Dispose();
                }
```

Also use the using() { } for the ImportIO class

```
    using(ImportIO myIO = new ImportIO) {  }
```

Comment: Managed memory is not freed when an object is disposed. Managed memory is freed by the garbage collector when it determines that an object is no longer reachable. (Short version of GC avoiding details like generations etc.)

Comment: I added above but still no help. May you please find my ImportIO class and suggest something? Please see above edit in my question.