# Unsubscribe event using dispose in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Actually I m trying to close my window by firing the event from my `ViewModel`. Everything works fine and awesome, but I know that I must unsbscribe my event to avoid memory leaks. thus I implement the `IDisposable` interface and I unsbscribe the event inside the `Dispose` method.

Below is my code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IDisposable
{
    private MainViewModel viewModel;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel =  new MainViewModel();
        this.viewModel.RequestClose += CloseWindow;
    }

    void CloseWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ////here we need to unsubscribe the event
        this.viewModel.RequestClose -= this.CloseWindow;
    }
}
```

What I need to know :

1. Is that code correct
2. When the `GC` will be called and excute the dispose method
3. Is there a better way to do such a thing

Comment: in this setup you don't need to unsubscribe the event at all - the event will hold a pointer to the window that's true, but when there is no path to the window there will be no path to the viewmodel as well and so it will be collected IFF the window will

Comment: As a heads up; you might want to read into some proper `IDispose` implementations. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336856/implementing-idisposable-correctly , http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P)

Comment: @Carsten can you explain more and in which case we must implement the dispose method

Comment: Try use a Attached behavior, actually I'm not a big fan of events, especially in MVVM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but I know that I must unsbscribe my event to avoid memory leaks

Memory leak occurs, when short-lived object subscribes an event of long-lived objects (or static event), and does not unsubscribe later (e.g., see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526840/580053) answer). I suppose, that this is not your case.

> When the GC will be called and excute the dispose method

GC doesn't call `IDisposable.Dispose` (e.g., see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45049/580053) answer). At all.
If you haven't any code, that calls `MainWindow.Dispose` explicitly, it will be called never.

> Is there a better way to do such a thing

I'd avoid `IDisposable` and events. Attached behavior here is more convenient, IMO (at least, this is reusable):

```
public static class WindowClosingBehavior
{
        public static bool GetIsClosingInitiated(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsClosingInitiatedProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsClosingInitiated(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsClosingInitiatedProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsClosingInitiatedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsClosingInitiated", 
            typeof(bool), 
            typeof(WindowClosingBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, IsClosingInitiatedChanged));

        private static void IsClosingInitiatedChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = target as Window;
            if (window != null && (bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                window.Close();
            }
        }
}
```

Somewhere in window's XAML:

```
behaviors:WindowClosingBehavior.IsClosingInitiated="{Binding IsClosingInitiated}"
```

where `IsClosingInitiated` is a property from view model:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
     // ...

     private void Foo()
     {
         // ...
         IsClosingInitiated = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to use Attached property

Comment: Dennis can you provide me with an example of events using that caused a  memory leaks

Comment: @MoezRebai: just subscribe any static event (e.g., `CommandManager.RequerySuggested`) from any short-lived object, and you'll get memory leak (without un-subscription).

Answer (score 4):

You only need to unsubscribe events when the source and the handler have different lifetimes, otherwise they both go out of scope at the same time and they are garbage collected together.

So in this case IDisposable is not needed. Anyway if you implement IDisposable you need to explicitly call it, otherwise you don't have control about when it is called.

Comment: So what do you think about calling the dispose method inside the CloseWindow method

Comment: I would prefer to handle the closing method of the view outside the view and calling the dispose there to maintain the single responsibility principle.

Answer (score 1):

Actually when the `Window.CloseWindow` subscribe to the event, it makes the view model point to the window.

The reverse is also true because there is a `ViewModel` field in the `Window`.

Both window and view model reference to each other.

If there is no other reference to them, garbage collection will make the job.

`Dispose` will be called if some code calls it.

To my knowledge, it won't happen, unless you surround the creation of the windows with a `using` or explicitly call `Dispose`

The best way here is to not implement `IDisposable` / `Dispose` : keep it simple.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'd say using an event is a more than acceptable method of achieving this. For a more *complete* dispose pattern, use the following snippet:

```
#region IDisposable

//Dispose() calls Dispose(true)
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

// NOTE: Delete the finalizer if this class doesn't 
// own unmanaged resources itself.
~ClassName() 
{
    //Finalizer calls Dispose(false)
    Dispose(false);
}

//The bulk of the clean-up code is implemented in Dispose(bool)
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing) 
    {
        //free managed resources (Example below)
        if (managedResource != null)
        {
            managedResource.Dispose();
            managedResource = null;
        }
    }

    //Free native resources if there are any. (Example below)
    if (nativeResource != IntPtr.Zero) 
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(nativeResource);
        nativeResource = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}

#endregion
```

In your case, your dispose method will be this:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

~MainWindow()
{
    Dispose();
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing) 
    {
        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            viewModel.RequestClose -= CloseWindow;
            viewModel.Dispose();
            viewModel = null;
        }
    }
}
```

As pointed out by Dennis, you'll need to keep the finalizer to ensure that `Dispose` gets called when the `MainWindow` is closed, for example in the event of the application being exited.

Comment: There's one tiny problem. **Who** will call `Dispose` in the sample from OP?

Comment: @Dennis That is an excellent point. If OP isn't managing `Dispose` (which I assume he isn't), he could add a **destructor** in his `MainWindow`.

Comment: Do you know, that finalizer (destructor) should release only *unmanaged* resources (while event is a pure *managed* resource)? Also, do you know, that one can't predict, when finalizer will be called?