# How to close a StreamReader/StreamWriter stream object as a class member?

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

If I have a class with the file stream members like so:

```
public class FooBar
{
    private StreamReader reader;
    private StreamWriter writer;

    public FooBar(string readerFilePath, string writerFilePath)
    {
        reader = new StreamReader(readerFilePath);
        writer = new StreamWriter(writerFilePath);
    }

    ...
}
```

then how do I close those streams?

It seems that they are closed by default during the class destruction, but then I have to use `writer.Flush()` which doesn't sound good.

Comment: FooBar should implement IDisposable. See [Implement IDisposable correctly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Implementing IDisposable correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18337005/2066142)

Comment: Still don't get the reason behind the IDisposable Interface if I have to explicitly call the Dispose() method. In my particular case I cannot use the `using` keyword. If I try to call the `writer.Close()` in the destructor (the way I would do it in C++), I get an exception telling that the stream has been already closed.

Comment: Maybe I have to learn how the garbage collector works...

Comment: [Cleaning Up Unmanaged Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/unmanaged)

Answer (score 0):

use using block

```
using(reader = new StreamReader(readerFilePath))
{
  //your code
}
```

from the below links:
 Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.

> From MSDN:
>
> C#, through the .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR),
>   automatically releases the memory used to store objects that are no
>   longer required. The release of memory is non-deterministic; memory is
>   released whenever the CLR decides to perform garbage collection.
>   However, it is usually best to release limited resources such as file
>   handles and network connections as quickly as possible.
>
> The using statement allows the programmer to specify when objects that
>   use resources should release them. The object provided to the using
>   statement must implement the IDisposable interface. This interface
>   provides the Dispose method, which should release the object's
>   resources. In other words, the using statement tells .NET to release
>   the object specified in the using block once it is no longer needed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

[What is the C# Using block and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it)