# Difference between ExecuteAsync and StartAsync methods in BackgroundService .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, migration, background-service

Migrating from the legacy .NET Framework I need to create a long time background process worker.

Looking at the documentation I found a `BackgroundService` class, which is used for this kind of purpose. But I stumbled across two the same (for my point of view) methods `ExecuteAsync()` and `StartAsync()`

Can somebody explain to me what the main difference between them?
Is it some kind of segregation principle - we have a method for setting up data as the "constructor" and we have a method for actually doing things?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The default behavior of the `BackgroundService` is that  `StartAsync` calls `ExecuteAsync`, see [code](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/BackgroundService.cs). It's a default, the `StartAsync` is `virtual` so you could override it.

Please note that only [`StartAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice.startasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_BackgroundService_StartAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) is `public` and [`ExecuteAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice.executeasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_BackgroundService_ExecuteAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)
`protected` (and `abstract`). So from the outside `StartAsync` is called

If you create a subclass of `BackgroundService`, you **must** implement `ExecuteAsync` (because it's `abstract`). That should do your work.  Also you *could* override `StartAsync` (as it's `virtual`), but that's only needed for special cases.

#### So why is there a StartAsync and ExecuteAsync?

You could create a service by implementing [`IHostedService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1). That interface has `StartAsync` and `StopAsync`.

`BackgroundService` is an (base) implementation of `IHostedService`, and could be used for long running tasks. This one defines the abstract `ExecuteAsync`.

#### In summary

- When inheriting from `BackgroundService`, implement `ExecuteAsync`
- When implementing `IHostedService`, implement `StartAsync` and `StopAsync`

#### Read more

- [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)
- [BackgroundService in .NET Core for long running tasks](https://medium.com/@daniel.sagita/backgroundservice-for-a-long-running-work-3debe8f8d25b) - also other implementations of IHostedService are shown here, like a TimedHostedService

Comment: You typically don't need to override `StartAsync`. It is there as a part of `IHostedService` implementation. All the work should be done in `ExecuteAsync`.

Comment: Yes indeed! Updated my post to make it more clear. Thanks!

Comment: I would just be interested in your opinion - I think `BackgroundService` doesn't implement `IDisposable` properly as `CancellationTokenSource` is managed type so I would expect to see code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18337005/3242721). So if this class doesn't even implement `IDisposable` as it should, is there any point in using it rather than implementing `IHostedService`?

Comment: The point to consider is that even though `ExecuteAsync` is async method, asynchronous calls (with `await` keyword) will not be awaited. So, if we use part of `ExecuteAsync` as a kind of startup and we need its results during or before app initialization, we should use them synchronously before first awaited call.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Reid K's answer (edited by Eric Aya)...including the `base.StartAsync()` - which vs2022 gives you by default - will solve the problem.

```
        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to [Julian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201303/julian)'s answer, I have noticed if you do override StartAsync when using the BackgroundWorker, ExecuteAsync will not get called. I am not sure if you are supposed call ExecuteAsync from StartAsync, but my impression was StartAsync runs before ExecuteAsync and before the backgroundservice runs. But the behavior I am seeing is that if you override StartAsync, ExecuteAsync will not automatically get called. Remove the override to StartAsync, and ExecuteAsync gets called automatically.

Comment: I noticed the same thing and found that if I return `base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);` from my overridden `StartAsync` method, `ExecuteAsync` will still get called.
Looking at the code via the link in Julian's answer, the virtual `StartAsync` method calls  ExecuteAsync (`_executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);`), so I suppose you could do the same in your overridden StartAsync method (return a call to your overridden ExecuteAsync method from StartAsync).
But I feel calling `base.StartAsync()` and letting the framework handle that is probably better?

Comment: @Reid K This is because `ExecuteAsync ` is called from original `StartAsync `. If you override it, then you have to repeat [original code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e3ffd343ad5bd3a999cb9515f59e6e7a777b2c34/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L37) too.