# ASP.NET Core minimal API Windows service with OnPause functionality?

Tags: c#, windows-services, asp.net-core-webapi

Currently I am using an ASP.NET Core Web API as a Windows service like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/hello", () => "Hello World");
```

With older .NET Framework Windows services, I have the possibility to overwrite the `OnPause` and `OnContinue` functionality.

Now I need something similar for my API Windows service.

I need to be able to pause and continue the service and execute logic within these events.

I could not find anything regarding these requirements.

Does anyone have an idea if that is possible and how to realize that?

Answer (score 0):

Both `OnPause` and `OnContinue` are based on [ServiceBase Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onpause?view=netframework-4.8.1), which does not apply .NET Core.

When using the .NET Core program as a Windows service, you need to install the [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices/8.0.0-preview.3.23174.8) Nuget package to use the [`BackgroundService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), which inherits from `IHostedService`. This does not include `OnPause`, `OnContinue`, etc., it only has `ExecuteAsync`, `StartAsync` and `StopAsync`.

Here are a few documents that can help you better understand the issues related to .NET Core as a Windows Service:

[Difference between ExecuteAsync and StartAsync methods in BackgroundService .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60356396/difference-between-executeasync-and-startasync-methods-in-backgroundservice-net).

[Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).