# when object goes out of scope in c #?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, destructor

Method where scopes defined explicitly.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Class1 c1 = new Class1(1);

    {
        Class1 c2 = new Class1(2);

        {
            Class1 c3 = new Class1(3);
        }

    //this is not collecting object c3 which is out of scope here
    GC.Collect();
    }

    //this is not collecting object c2 which is out of scope here
    GC.Collect();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Class1 definition:

```
class Class1
{
    int x;
    public Class1(int a)
    {
        x = a;
    }
    ~Class1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x + "object destroy");
    }
}
```

I write this code. But GC.Collect() method don't collect the object which goes out of scope.

Comment: Actually if you built in release mode without a debugger attached you would see c1 c2 and c3 all get cleaned up at the first GC.Collect() because a variable "goes out of scope" after the last time it is used in the function when in release mode.

Comment: @huzefa: How do you know "method don't collect the object which goes out of scope"? How did you test that?

Comment: @CharithJ  - i write a msg in Class1 destructor. and i don't get that msg in console screen.by that i know the object don't get garbage collected.

Comment: @huzefa: Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @CharithJ  as u say in your updated answer that Garbage collector doesn't take inner scopes into account when clearing memory. But look at my answer also when i refer object with null GC collect the object. so why it  collect only when object refer by null but not when it goes out of scope? is referring null is different from "out of scope" ??

Comment: @huzefa:Yes, setting null is different. It changes the reference of c2 and as a result the previously created object doesn't have any references. So, GC is certain that it is not referred by anything any more. Whereas in the previous case, GC doesn't want to take a risk and execute the finalizer while you are in the same local scope (in the same method with a reference).

Comment: **Collection does not run finalizers**.  That is your first fundamental misunderstanding.  Collection makes objects eligible for finalization by the finalizer thread. Your second fundamental misunderstanding is that **scope and eligibility for collection have almost nothing to do with each other**. The runtime is perfectly free to extend or shorten the lifetimes of references in locals as it sees fit.

Comment: If you want a correct understanding of finalization semantics then you might start by reading my articles on the subject. http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/

Answer (score 1):

`GC.Collect()` isn't really meant to be used for deterministic reclamation of resources. (That is what your finalizers in your real code is doing, right?)

If you have an unmanaged resource to deal with, strong consider using one of the classes in `Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles`.

If you want deterministic release of resources, you should implement `IDisposable`, and call `Dispose()` when you are done using the object. The idiomatic way of doing this is:

```
using (var someResource = new Class1(1)) 
{
    // work with the `Class1` object
}
```

which is functionally equivalent to

```
{
    var someResource = new Class1(1);
    try 
    { 
        // work with the `Class1` object 
    }
    finally
    {
        someResource.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you think about scoping is correct. Objects are going out of scope exactly as you expect. However, apparently the way you are testing it is not so correct.

Couple of points to consider here.

1. You should **implement the finalizer *only if* you have any unmanaged resources**.
   If your class has a finalizer and if you don’t [implement IDisposable Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31016954/591656) in a way that it the suppress the finalization, instances of that class can reside in memory for two garbage collection cycles. Because, the first GC.Collect add that instance to the finalization queue if it requires finalization. May be the second garbage collection cycle actually clears the memory.
2. Finalizer is the last point where .net objects can release unmanaged resources. 
   Finalizers are to be executed only if you don’t dispose your instances correctly. Ideally, finalizers should never be executed. Because proper dispose implementation should suppress the finalization.
3. According to your sample code, if you call [GC.Collect and WaitForPendingFinalizers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954829/gc-collect-and-finalize) your test may pass (not sure how to find if memory is cleared).

**Better test for you.**

Garbage collector doesn't take inner scopes into account when clearing memory. If you move your code into a separate method it executes the finalizer.

**Test 1**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GCTest();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    private static void GCTest()
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1(1);

        {
            Class1 c2 = new Class1(2);

            {
                Class1 c3 = new Class1(3);
            }

            //this is not collecting object c3 which is out of scope here
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }

        //this is not collecting object c2 which is out of scope here
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
```

**Test 2**

Use [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) if you want to specify scoping for garbage collection purposes.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Class1 c1 = new Class1(1))
        {
            using (Class1 c2 = new Class1(2))
            {
                Class1 c3 = new Class1(3);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    class Class1 : IDisposable
    {
        int x;
        public Class1(int a)
        {
            x = a;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x + "object disposing");
        }
    }
```

*Output*

> 2object disposing
>
> 1object disposing

Answer (score 0):

Theses scopes do not make it into IL. The runtime has no idea they were there. At the IL level there are just locals and stack contents. Although the .NET JIT is poor in general it does a decent job of optimizing locals and temporary values into an efficient form.

There are no guarantees when objects will be collected. `GC.Collect` can't force that. There are some safe patterns to have it 99.999% guaranteed but never fully.

You never need this facility. In fact the need to have a finalizer is almost zero. Use the `SafeHandle` infrastructure.

If you really want to see the effect, move all of this code into a helper method and call that from `Main`. Back in main the `Collect` will succeed.