# GC collect and wait, but still memory used?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

As we all know this is how garbage collection should be forced

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Also C# allows us to check amount of memory currently in use.

```
GC.GetTotalMemory(false) // do not wait for GC
```

But when I call two collect and wait methods, then getting memory used I still see that memory is not cleared.

```
public class MemoryUsage
{
    private byte[] mmr;
    public MemoryUsage()
    {
        mmr = new byte[10000000]; // ~10 MB
    }

    ~MemoryUsage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Finalizer");
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Initial memory usage: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false)));

    MemoryUsage m1 = new MemoryUsage();
    MemoryUsage m2 = new MemoryUsage();
    MemoryUsage m3 = new MemoryUsage();

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("I use memory: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false)));
    m1 = null;
    m2 = null;
    m3 = null;

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("I did collect and waited, but memory still: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false)));

    GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("I only got amount of memory and: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false)));
}
```

App is built in Release mode, result is:

```
Initial memory usage: 47568
I use memory: 30062576
Finalizer
Finalizer
Finalizer
I did collect and waited, but memory still: 30070520
I only got amount of memory and: 62184
```

What I found is that I can call just GC.GetTotalMemory(true) instead of WaitForPendingFinalizers and all finalizers are finished.

Is there any other way to make sure that GC finished? Thanks

Comment: But why are you use `finalizer` instead of `dispose`? `Finalizer` should be used to release unmanaged memory and I do not see that you have unmanaged memory here, try implement dispose pattern and set `byte[]` to `null` within dispose...

Comment: Read this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954829/gc-collect-and-finalize...

Comment: @Johnny this is only for test purpose, I don't get why classes with finalizers are not cleared after WaitForPendingFinalizers

Comment: @Johnny I got it, have to call Collect second time, was a bit not obvious for me, thank you!

Comment: Exactly, I was in the middle of the comment... ;)

Comment: The finalizer runs *after* a collection.  So a class object with a finalizer cannot be collected right away, the CLR merely sets a bit in the object header to indicate that it was finalized.  The next collection destroys it.