# Open windows in background

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm opening a second window in my main window. This window is used to display a progress bar, so I don't want to block my application when it is open.

My code is:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IDisposable
{
    private void doUpdate(object sender, UpdateInfosArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            using (DownloadingFileWindow dlw = new DownloadingFileWindow())
            {
                dlw.OnDownloadFileComplete += OnDownloadFileComplete;
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => dlw.ShowDialog()));
                // or dlw.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, when the window is shown, it is closed immediately when execution reaches the `}` of the `using`.

Is there a way to way that windows is closed?

Answer (score 2):

To open a dialog as non-modal (non-blocking) you need to use `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()`.

Your second problem is your `using` statement. This *disposes* `dlw` again at the end of the `using` block, which closes the window.

So try this:

```
private void doUpdate(object sender, UpdateInfosArgs e)
{
    DownloadingFileWindow dlw = new DownloadingFileWindow();
    dlw.OnDownloadFileComplete += OnDownloadFileComplete;
    dlw.Show();
}
```

I don't think it's necessary to call `Dispose()` on the child window explicitly. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568408/what-is-the-correct-way-to-dispose-of-a-wpf-window) for a discussion of that.

Comment: You right, my using was disposing my window. Do I have to override `DownloadingFileWindow.OnClose` to properly call the Dispose function ?

Comment: @A.Pissicat added a link to a question discussing the `Dispose()` question

Answer (score 1):

The dialog will close after the using, because the using bracket cleans the object after finished the task in the using bracket.

To keep it open after your using bracket, you must not initiate the ressource for the using.

```
DownloadingFileWindow dlw = new DownloadingFileWindow()
dlw.OnDownloadFileComplete += OnDownloadFileComplete;
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => dlw.ShowDialog()));
```

And within the Dialog itself, implement a closing routine like this.close(); by a trigger.

Comment: It's better without using but ShowDialog always block mainWindows. With `dlw.Show()` it is better